# BIML using umlauts in table name

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, biml

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with BIML Express.

My script has a fairly simple data flow task:

```
<Dataflow Name="Sync Table Währungen">
    <PrecedenceConstraints>
            <Inputs>
                    <Input OutputPathName="Truncate Währungen.Output" />
                </Inputs>
        </PrecedenceConstraints>
        <Transformations>
            <OleDbSource Name="Währungen Source" ConnectionName="Source">
                <ExternalTableInput Table="[dbo].[Währungen]" />
            </OleDbSource>
            <OleDbDestination Name="Währungen Destination" ConnectionName="Destination" CheckConstraints="false" KeepIdentity="true" KeepNulls="true">
                <ExternalTableOutput Table="[dbo].[Währungen]" />
            </OleDbDestination>
        </Transformations>
</Dataflow>
```

The generation of the Package fails with errors:

```
Expanding Biml
1/1 Emitting Project Sync.dtproj.
1/1 Emitting Package Sync.
Error   0   FlowFramework, Version=5.0.61915.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=015f370a62f9a1a3. Node W�hrungen Source: Could not execute Query on Connection BADSQLOLTPTEST\OLTPTEST.Zentrale:

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[W�hrungen]

Die verzögerte Bereitstellung konnte nicht beendet werden.
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Invalid object name 'dbo.W�hrungen'.        -1  -1
```

Using a table name with no special characters will generate a package.

How can I change the script to use umlauts?

Comment: Coming at this from the other side, do you *need* to use umlauts in anything but the actual SQL?

Comment: No I do not. Unfortunately the problem still persists if I leave the umlauts in the table values. These I have to use because the tables can't be renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right then!  So this was an interesting little challenge...

Turns out that you can replace characters in your Biml scripts with their [HTML Entity](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e4/index.htm) equivalent (and probably others, though I haven't checked).  This means that in your case, you can substitute your `ä` characters with `&#228;` and everything should work.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. I tried &auml; before, but it was not working.

Comment: No worries!  Glad you got it sorted :)